# Heroku fails pushing to master branch

Tags: git, heroku

I wonder why I can't push to heroku master even if I already logged in and added the keys. I already did pushed on my first build but now no luck. I did searched for some answers but got same issue. I also tried to remove the remote branch and added back but no luck again.

Command

```
git push heroku master
```

Result

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/project.git/': Failed to connect to git.heroku.com port 443: Timed out
```

Comment: you have a network problem, not a git problem

Comment: @OznOg thank for the clue man

Answer (score 2):

You need package file. In js it is usually `package.json`
Depends on what language you used and what it is meant to be used for.

Find out what are major files that are required so heroku can push your project through.

Comment: True, my package.json has no issues because I did a successful push and failed on the next day. Fixing network issue solved the problem.